# Table coloring with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

I'm trying to have get a background color at my tables consisting of both `multirows` and `multicolums`. Without any color, the table works fine. But what I want to color expands over variable amounts of rows. I've tried to color four rows with the same color, with one cell stretching over four rows and one cell stretching over two rows.

But if I do that the second coloring, applies the color on top of the multirow text. 
[image: table wouthout color]

[image: table with text]

As you can see, the second line of `rowcolor` removes the upper part of 'Grade' from `cell 1` and third row color removed the lower part of 'Grade' and lower part of Thickness. Any solution ideas?

my tex:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll|}
\hline
\rowcolor{blue!20} 
\multirow{4}{*}{Grades}&Yield&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Impact bending test}\\
\rowcolor{blue!20}
                      &Strength&\multirow{2}{*}{Thickness}&Test& Impact\\
\rowcolor{blue!20}
                             &$\mathbf{R_e[N/mm^2]}$&                                &{\bf temperature}     & {\bf work}\\
\rowcolor{blue!20}
                             &\bf{transv.min.}      &\bf{ transv.}                   &$\mathbf{[\grader]}$  & {\bf [J]} \\\hline
\multirow{ 1}{*}{{\bf DH36}}   &     & {\bf 5.5 – 7.0} & {\bf         -40} & {\bf       24} \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: the - in \multirow{-2}{*}{ } doesnt work for me.. it just moves the text outside the table

Comment: Please, extend your code sniped to complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}`, with necessary packages and your new commands definitions and ending with `end{document}`. In present state it is not possible to compile. Welcome to site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on guessing about your preamble and meaning of used commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{detect-weight=true}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{\bfseries}c|}
                 *{3}{>{\bfseries}c}|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{blue!20}
                &   &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Impact bending test}}    \\
\rowcolor{blue!20}
\multirow{-2}*{Grades}  
        &   \multirow{-3}*[-1ex]{\makecell{Yield\\  Strength\\ 
                                            {$\mathbf{R_e[\si{N\per\milli\meter^2}]}$} \\transv. min.}}
                    &   \makecell{Thickness\\  transv.}    
                        &   \makecell{Test\\ temperature\\ \si{\celsius}}
                            &   \makecell{Impact\\ work\\ \si{J} }          \\
    \hline
DH36   &       & 5.5 – 7.0 & -40   & 24    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
macro `makecell` have options `b` for bottom position, `t` for top position, `l` for left aligned cell content and `r` for right aligned. Use of it without options the cell content is vertically and horizontally centered.

If in above MWE replace the second row of table with

```
\multirow{-3}*{Grades}
        &   \multirow{-3}*[3pt]{\makecell{Yield\\  Strength\\
                                            {$\mathbf{R_e[\si{N\per\milli\meter^2}]}$} \\transv. min.}}
                    &   \makecell[b]{Thickness\\  transv.}
                        &   \makecell[b]{Test\\ temperature\\ \si{\celsius}}
                            &   \makecell[b]{Impact\\ work\\ \si{J} }          \\
```

than the table is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Probably, you should use `[detect-weight=true]`.

Comment: @Bernard, yes, this is right key for `siunitx`, I consider this in edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You won't see thin white lines, wathever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{detect-weight=true}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|ccc|}[cell-space-top-limit=3pt]
\Hline
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=blue!20]{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{Grades} 
   & \Block{2-1}{Yield\\ Strength\\ $\mathbf{R_e[\unit{N\per\milli\meter^2}]}$ \\transv. min.}  
     & \Block{1-3}{Impact bending test}  \\
   &   
     & \Block{}{Thickness\\  transv.}    
       & \Block{}{Test\\ temperature\\ \unit{\celsius}}
          & \Block{}{Impact\\ work\\ \unit{J}}   \\
\Hline
DH36  &  & $5.5$ -- $7.0$ & $-40$ & $24$    \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]